Lax-Milgram and fundamental quadratic problems in real Hilbert spaces using convexity.
I am working on understanding and verifying a way to approach the Lax-Milgram theorem and fundamental quadratic problems in real Hilbert spaces. Below is the reasoning I have followed, based on ideas presented in my university lectures:

I consider the function $ F(x) := \dfrac{1}{2} B(x, x) - b(x) $, where:


$ B $ is a symmetric, bounded, and coercive bilinear form
$ b $ is a continuous linear form.


Since $ B $ is coercive and bounded, it follows that $ B $ is uniformly convex. Additionally, $ b $, being linear, is convex. Hence, $ F $ is uniformly convex.

The function $ F $ is also continuous (and therefore lower-semicontinuous). Since $ H $ is a Hilbert space, and therefore a Banach space, $ F $ must attain a minimum in $ H $, which is also unique.

At the minimum, the differential of $ F $ vanishes. By the Riesz-Fréchet theorem, there exists a unique $ y \in H $ such that $ b(x) = \langle x, y \rangle $, and then:
$$
   dF(x)(z) = B(x, z) - \langle z, y \rangle.
   $$

At the minimum $ x $, we have $ 0 = B(x, z) - \langle z, y \rangle $ for all $ z \in H $. This implies $ \langle z, y \rangle = B(x, z) $ for all $ z $, thereby proving both theorems (Lax-Milgram and the fundamental quadratic problems) in a single reasoning.


My question is:

Is this reasoning correct in its entirety?
Are there any points that I should clarify or consider more carefully?

I would greatly appreciate any comments or corrections. Thank you!
